# How to register hitTest only if Mouse Down is true?

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, flashdevelop, flash-cs6, hittest

I was wondering on how to register a Hittest between two Movie Clips only if the `MOUSE_DOWN` event is equal to true.

So I have a Movie Clip called `playerHook` that acts as the Mouse and whenever that movie clip comes in contact with another movie clip called `octopusBoss` and Clicks on it I want it to register a hittest and subtract a point from its health.

Here is what I have so far but not sure what to do next:

In my main constructor function:

```
playerHook.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playerHookMove);
playerHook.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMDown);
playerHook.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMUp);
```

Then I have two booleas set up in the two functions onMDown and onMUp:

```
private function onMDown(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    mouseIsDown = true;
}

private function onMUp(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    mouseIsUp = false;          

}
```

Then I have this function which is currently in my gameloop that I would want to happen only if the user clicks on the OctopusBoss:

```
private function checkPlayerHitOctopusBoss():void 
{
    if (playerHook.hitTestObject(octopusBoss))
    {
         trace("Hit Octopus");
         octopusBossHealth --;              
    }else 
    if (octopusBossHealth <= 0)
    {
         octopusBoss.destroyOctopusBoss();
    }
}
```

But I am having trouble passing the mouse booleans to the `if` statement. I know I am  missing something crucial!

Comment: Is mouseIsDown in the same scope with checkPlayerHitOctopusBoss function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need some name to your `octopusBoss` like so:

`octopusBoss.name = "octopusBoss"`;

Modify your `onMDown` function  like so:

```
private function onMDown(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    if(e.target.name == "octopusBoss") //Check if octopusBoss is under mouse
    mouseIsDown = true;
}
```

And your `checkPlayerHitOctopusBoss` function like so:

```
private function checkPlayerHitOctopusBoss():void 
{
   if (playerHook.hitTestObject(octopusBoss) && mouseIsDown) // check mouse down
   {
       trace("Hit Octopus");
       octopusBossHealth --;              
   }else 
   if (octopusBossHealth <= 0)
   {
       octopusBoss.destroyOctopusBoss();
   }
}
```

UPDATE:
If it's ok to add `MouseEvents` directly to `octopusBoss` like so:

`octopusBoss.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMDown);`
`octopusBoss.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMUp);`

Then, you can also use `e.currentTarget.name`.

Comment: I added that to the hittest function last night. Then i tried to add your e.target.name if statement. But it doesnt seem to work. I tried to trace it but it doesnt seem to be working when my mouse is over the boss, nothing happens

Comment: Whenever i just test the regular hittest it works fine. But when i add && mouseIsDown to the if statement nothing happens.

Comment: That is perfect it works great mean thanks so much for all your help I tried the currentTarget earlier but didnt work because i didnt have the other part on the mouse event. I have one more question though when the hit test does register and i trace the hit, it hits it for each frame. so i get the trace 28 times. Is their away to fix this such as stating somewhere that mouseIsDown is = false; ?

Comment: Nevermind i figured it out. Just added the boolean inside the if statement